# AngularJS $injector:unpr issue with Angular Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dependency-injection, angularjs-injector

So i'm getting a Error: [$injector:unpr] when I try and inject $modal into my controller.

here is what I have:

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers", ['services', 'ngCookies','ngStorage','ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

controllers.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'configurationData', 'dashboardData', 'orderByFilter', '$cookieStore' , 'isstevenFilterArray', '$rootScope', '$modal' , function ($scope, $http, $location, configurationData, dashboardData, orderByFilter, $cookieStore, isstevenFilterArray, $rootScope, $modal)

<script src="vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `<script src="vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js">` line at the top. After that only you should be creating module and controllers.

### Try below code:

```
<script src="vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

var controllers = angular.module("controllers", ['services', 'ngCookies','ngStorage','ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

controllers.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'configurationData', 'dashboardData', 'orderByFilter', '$cookieStore' , 'isstevenFilterArray', '$rootScope', '$modal' , function ($scope, $http, $location, configurationData, dashboardData, orderByFilter, $cookieStore, isstevenFilterArray, $rootScope, $modal)
```